# Angular JS $http call returns status code 0

Tags: angularjs, request

I currently have stumbled upon a weird problem in angular JS, when making an http call. After I execute a POST request, after waiting around 2-3 minutes, the call fails, returning:

- status code 0
- "null" response data
- empty response text

  ```
      $.support.cors = true;
      var req = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: serverIp + "UpdateDocumentInventar",
          headers: {
              'codDocument': CodDocument,
              'deviceId': deviceId,
              'authToken': authToken,
              'codGestiune': codGestiune
          },
          timeout: timeoutNR,
          data: articoleChanged   <--- array of items
      }
      var request = $http(req);

      return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
  ```

The web server isn't reached, since I have put loggers there to see whether there is the problem or not.

I also need to mention that this call does not always fail - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
(I have read on the net that status code 0 is usually associated with not setting the CORS - I have also set this, and this surely is not the problem, as other similar requests are executed correctly).

What have I tried until now:
 - set the timeout value of the http request to a bigger one (60000000)
 - set a bigger accepted length of an http request on the server (I thought that this might me a problem aswell, although this usually returns status code 41)

Every help is apreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to check your API/service working properly thru some other tools like fiddler or postman? And check your POST request is working with required parameters.